# JPanel inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a problem because I want to put a small `JPanel` inside a different `JPanel`, but I can't get the small `JPanel` to show.

What am I missing?

```
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));

    this.cardsPanel= new JPanel();
    this.cardsPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    this.cardsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.CENTER,3,10));

    this.cardsPanel2= new JPanel();
    this.cardsPanel2.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    this.cardsPanel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.CENTER,3,10));

    this.tablePanel=new JPanel();
    this.tablePanel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    this.tablePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.CENTER,5,5));

    this.tablePanel1=new JPanel();
    this.tablePanel1.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    this.tablePanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
   // this.tablePanel1.setLayout(null);
    this.tablePanel1.add(tablePanel);

    this.add(cardsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.add(cardsPanel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(tablePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for faster help

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 1):

Using that code:

- Neither `cardsPanel1` nor `cardsPanel2` (dark gray) have any components (or therefore) any size.  At 0x0 pixels size, **they are invisible** even when added to another container (unless the layout stretches them).
- `tablePanel` (pink) **should be visible** so long as `this` is assigned enough space in whatever layout *it* is added to.
- `tablePanel1` (orange) **should not be visible** as it is never added to anything.

But as mentioned, for better help sooner, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0):

`this.validate();` your root panel after adding new content.

Comment: 'this.tablePanel1.add(tablePanel);
 this.tablePanel.validate();' It doesn't work:(

Comment: Be more elaborate in your answer.